# Is there a way to change incoming sms text?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Can I change the text of incoming SMS, if I catch it with Broadcast Receiver?

Comment: Why you wanted to do this? you can stop the message to go in the inbox

Comment: You can also stop the broadcast of notifications also. Why would you want to change the content of incoming SMS?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, No - it's not possible to change the SMS text.

The maximum that your application can do is receive and customize the UI for display (in your app only). However, there may be yet another application that shows SMS in a different style.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I found the way - you can edit SQLite DB, which contains SMS/MSS :)